# Float:right causing anchor to stretch with line-height

Tags: html, css

I want to position my `anchor` to middle (vertical) inside a fixed `div`.
I can't use `display:table/table-cell` because of other content inside my `div`, so I thought line-height would be the best alternative.

My problem is that the `anchor` will stretch out when I put `line-height` with it, but only if it's `floated`.

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed">
  <a class="btn" href="#">btn1</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
  position:fixed;
}

.btn
{
  padding: 3px 9px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  line-height:100px;
  float:right;
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/828zrzrk/

Comment: Do you want to center the `<a>`? Just add `text-align:center;` to `.fixed` and remove `float:right;` from `.btn`.

Comment: Why don't you remove position fixed from the div and only sets the padding property on .btn?

Comment: Sorry I meant vertical align, not horizontal

Answer (score 0):

add display:block;
change padding value.

```css
.fixed
{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:grey;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
}

.btn
{
  display:block;
  padding: 0 9px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  line-height:100px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <a class="btn" href="#">btn1</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```
.btn {

```
**
width: WIDTH;
height: HEIGHT;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -WIDTH/2;
margin-left: -HEIGHT/2;
```

}
```

[Demo](https://codeide.co/w3stacks/KogkiVFs)